# Rails4 + Bootstrap3 - Modals render but won't show

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm using Rails 4, Bootstrap 3. The particular page in question is made up of 3 haml views. The first contains most of the page content. The second contains a row of buttons - one of which needs to trigger the modal. The third contains the modal.

Code for the first view is:

```
    <...bulk of page content...>
    = render partial: 'shared/buttons', locals: {diagram: @diagram}
    #showDetail.modal.fade{"aria-labelledby" => "showDetail", :role => dialog, :tabindex => "-1"}
```

Code for the second view ('shared/buttons'):

```
    <...links to several buttons that don't call modals...>
    = link_to "Show Detail", show_detail_path(item), class: "btn", data: {"toggle" => "modal", "target" => "#showDetail", "remote" => :true}
```

Code for the third view (items/_show_detail.html.haml, routed to 'show_detail_path'):

```
    .modal-dialog{:role => "document}
      .my_popup_contain
        .container-fluid
          <...rest of the code for the page...>
```

And in the controller:

```
    def show_detail
      render partial: "show_detail"
    end
```

So with this setup, clicking the button produces the page "fade" like the modal is going to appear, but it never does. Clicking again (anywhere) makes the page fade go away (just like it would if the modal displayed). The rails server logs show that the modal does render:

> Started GET "/items/4/show_detail" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-02-22 14:49:44 -0600
>   Processing by ItemsController#show_detail as JS
>     Parameters: {"id"=>"4"}
>     User Load (2.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
>     Item Load (1.5ms)  SELECT  "items".* FROM "items"  WHERE "items"."type" IN ('Item') AND "items"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 4]]
>     Rendered items/_show_detail.html.haml (1.1ms)
>   Completed 200 OK in 11ms (Views: 4.7ms | ActiveRecord: 3.6ms)

What am I missing? Are the calls between views correct?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by adding to code for the first view:

```
    <...bulk of page content...>
    = render partial: 'shared/buttons', locals: {diagram: @diagram}
    #showDetail.modal.fade{"aria-labelledby" => "showDetail", :role => dialog, :tabindex => "-1"}
      = render partial 'items/show_detail'
```

That calls the modal and all works as expected.